# QGIS choropleth map

Tags: qgis, choropleth

In QGIS, when I change from single symbol to a graduated style, the map "disappears." When I change it back to single symbol, the map "reappears." The issue doesn't appear to be the scale, since it remains unchanged. When I copy the layers into ArcMap, there is no problem. What is causing this problem?

Comment: don't forget to choose a field to base the classification on, then hit 'classify'...

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.